# Why my data from sqlite DB update only when I restart Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I have a problem with my Data from sqlite Database. I have to restart app to see results of every changes (adding note, update note or deleting note). I don't know how to fix it. Can someone tell me what is wrong or what I forgot in my code.

```
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _titleController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Note title",
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Note text',
              ),
            ),
            _NoteButton((widget.noteMode == NoteMode.Adding ? 'Save note' : 'Edit note'),
                widget.noteMode == NoteMode.Adding ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.yellow, () {
                  if (widget.noteMode == NoteMode.Adding) {
                    final title = _titleController.text;
                    final text = _textController.text;
                    NoteProvider.insertNote({
                      'title': title,
                      'text': text
                    });
                  }
                  else if (widget.noteMode == NoteMode.Editing){
                    NoteProvider.updateNote({
                      'id': widget.note?['id'],
                      'title': _titleController.text,
                      'text': _textController.text,
                    });
                  }
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
            ),
            widget.noteMode == NoteMode.Editing ?
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                child: _NoteButton('DELETE', Colors.red, () async {
                  await NoteProvider.deleteNote(widget.note?['id']);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }),
                ) : Container()
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

It looks like Nagigator.pop() didn't update my notes list.
Have I forgotten something?

**Notes list**

```
        future: NoteProvider.getNoteList(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot  snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            final notes = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  /*child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),*/
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                        NotePage(NoteMode.Editing, notes[index]))
                    );
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 30.0, bottom: 30.0, left: 13, right: 22),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _NoteTitle(notes[index]['title']),
                          Container(height: 3,),
                          _NoteText(notes[index]['text']),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: notes.length,
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state management package like Mobx for it, or you can call again your function to get data from your database, or you can use `FutureBuilder`, and whenever you edit, delete, or add new data, call `setState` to update your list.

Comment: I add Notes_list, where I am using `FutureBuilder`.  Have I forgotten something?

Comment: call `seState()` after action, to rebuild your widget. For example after `await NoteProvider.deleteNote(widget.note?['id']);`, put `setState()`.